# How do I remove column padding to have full-width inputs in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get rid of padding in Bootstrap 3's columns?

In the following plunkr, I'd like for the button and text input to be touching: http://plnkr.co/edit/H5EIiCyiH8HbploTghVZ?p=preview and for each to fill the entire width of the div.  I'd like them to have no left or right padding.  Same for the "pull me left" and "me too" divs.

When I override the padding-left in my own CSS, it pulls everything to the left, making the "Jim" and "Hello" div's content off screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a class to the row which removes padding from all immediate div elements with a class name beginning with "col-".

See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/MBkojy?p=preview

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to do what I want.  (Though I just abandoned bootstrap in favor of a much smaller custom grid system).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the entire code what you wanted :) Please give a try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<!-- Le styles -->
<link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 979px) {

    /* Remove any padding from the body */
    body {
      padding-top: 0;
    }
  }
</style>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="3.0.0" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Just a div

```
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">Jim</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">Hello</div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-right:0px !important; padding-left:0px !important">
                                        <button class="btn" class="col-xs-12" style="width:100%; float:right; background-color:green; ">Click</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6" style=" padding-left:0px !important; padding-right:0px !important">
                                        <input type="text" class="col-xs-12" style="width:100%;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">pull me left</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">me too</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have done it for the button and text input :) you can proceed in the same way :)

Comment: Thank you @Anobik, but I'm looking for a way to do it for all divs, not with the `style` attribute.  I should have said so.

Comment: try using a css class and assigning the class to the required divs. :)  use javascript or body onload function to assign the class to all those div which have button as a child and a textbox. use js getElementsByClassName and you will get an array and check for it.

Answer (score -2):

You can set all divs to no padding:

```
div {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

For the other two divs, you'll need to give them some named class (in my example 'padLeft') that return the left padding to the divs.

```
div.padLeft {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

That is the minimally invasive way to do it. If you have more div's where you want padding than not you simply inverse this, using a separate class for divs that you want the padding removed and leave the others to their default.

Comment: If I just do just `div {padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 0px !important;}` the divs overflow into each other.  But if I also set `margin-left: 0px !important; margin-right: 0px !important;` it looks right.

Comment: creating a div rule like the the first one is guaranteed to mess up stuff in ways you cannot imagine, use classes as far as possible.